# PDF signing using an API in a cloud hosted environment .NET - Azure with a CA certificate

Tags: azure, pdf-generation, digital-signature, acrobat, electronic-signature

Has anyone implemented this?

The solutions I have looked at all require a hardware token, which obviously won't work when cloud hosted.

I don't really want to pay for a SaaS to do the signing as the per document costs will be prohibitive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need a hardware token but you do need a certificate for signing PDFs, and most CAs sell such certificates (those that are accepted by Adobe applications) already installed to hardware.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, do you know of any CAs who sell certificates that aren't bound to hardware? it seems to me like those I've come across do require hardware tokens, which is problematic for a cloud hosted solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have such information.